# Getting error when entering valid credit card and cvv

Tags: contribution-page, stripe

When people try donate at this page they are getting a pink bar underneath the credit card entry line that says "Error" no other info on type of error. Credit card and and cvv are valid.

https://emptyhometax.org/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=1

[image]

Comment: I started getting that after updating to latest versions (CiviCRM 5.38, mjwshared (Payment Shared) 1.0, and Stripe Payment Processor 6.6), and flagged it here - https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/322.  It has been suggested that the 'firewall' extension might be causing this 'parse error' as that had solved it for someone else (disabling didn't solve it for me)

Comment: https://emptyhometax.org/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=1

A clue maybe that when I signed in to admin on my wordpress site and go the the live page above the payment is processed.

I am using a confirmation page. However, if I try in an incognito tab or have another person try on a different ip it give error as described and won't advance past initial page to confirmation page

Answer (score 2):

So I actually solved my issue by going to Wordpress Access Control under Users and Permissions. I just enabled the permissions for Anons under "CiviCRM: access AJAX API Allow API access even if Access CiviCRM is not granted". Payments are going through no problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a note that this problem can also be caused by the WordPress basepage being set to something other than 'civicrm'. There's no fix for this as  yet, with some discussion of potential issues [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20702).